# Границы QHBoxLayout и QVBoxLayout

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

Не могу убрать границы с QHBoxLayout и QVBoxLayout.
Как решить данную проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш пример и покажите на изображении что надо убрать.

Comment: Данила, вы уже задали много вопросов, но ни один ответ не отмечен вами как правильный. Вы должны как-то реагировать на предоставленные вам ответы и комментарии. Если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Границы у лейаутов отрисовываются только в режиме редактирования, при запуске их не будет. Если же и отрисовываются какие-либо границы при запуске, то это, видимо, границы фреймов, на которых лежат ваши лейауты